# Uploading files Kotlin Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, postman

So, I am trying to make and upload file(s) functionality, from some blog posts and stackoverflow questions I got this solution:

```
@PostMapping("/file/upload")
fun handleFileUpload(
    @RequestParam("files") files: List<MultipartFile>?,
): String {
    if(files == null) {
        return "File is null"
    }
    // SOME LOGIC
    return "All Good it seems"
}
```

But when I send request trough postman I my files are null, here is postman request:
[image: Postman]

I saw some some solutions that use `@RequestPart` instead of `@RequestParam`, but when I go down that path, I get `unsupported media type` response.

PS: I use Java 11 and Spring Boot 2.6

**UPDATE:**
Applied suggestions from comments and ended up with this code:

```
@PostMapping("/file/upload", consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])
fun handleFileUpload(
    @RequestPart("files") files: List<MultipartFile>?,
): String {
    //SOME CODE
}
```

When I send request trough postman I get `415 Unsupported Media Type`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@RequestPart List<MultipartFile>` and directly specify Content-Type in Postman
[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDO7A.png)

Comment: Tried it, when I send request like that I get `415 Unsupported Media Type`

Comment: @rosmak try to use MultipartFile[] not List<MultipartFile>

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Revasha's response, you should also add

`@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)`

on your endpoint to avoid the `415` http error

Comment: Added your suggestion as noted in updated question, and still get `415 Unsupported Media Type`

Comment: Also try using ```@ModelAttribute``` instead of ```@RequestParam```

Comment: When I add that I get exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface java.util.List`

Comment: Instead of ```List```, try using ```ArrayList``` or ```LinkedList```

Comment: Tried it, still same 415 response

Comment: Hm, try using files[0] on postman

Comment: Now I get 400 Bad Request

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use FilePart interface.
@RequestPart List

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).